# Htop display options

Tags: server, htop

I need help setting the second in the display options section. I accidentally pressed space too long on highlight time (in seconds), and now it is 2190, and I don't know how to lower it. I've tried to press and hold space, but it seems like it would go to a high number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least in htop 3.0.5, it appears that you can decrement the value using the <kbd>-</kbd> key.

If all else fails, you can always reset everything to the default values by deleting your `~/.config/htop/htoprc` file.